# Basic analysis question on uncountable sets

Tags: real-analysis

So, I have the following problem

Construct a function $f : [0,1] \to [0,1] $ so that $f$ takes every value uncountable often.

What does it mean "uncountable often" ??

Comment: This means the set $\{x\in [0,1], f(x)=y\}$ is uncountable for each $y$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the binary representation:

For $x\in [0,1]$, we write
 $$x = \sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}\dfrac{a_n}{2^n}$$ with $a_n \in \{0,1\}$ and no $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $a_n = 1, \forall n \geq N$

And we define $$f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}\dfrac{a_{2n+1}}{2^{n}}$$

Then for $y = \sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}\dfrac{b_n}{2^n} \in [0,1]$, the set $\{x\in [0,1], f(x)=y\}$ is equal to $$\{ x=\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}\dfrac{a_n}{2^n}, a_{2n+1} = b_n,\forall n\}$$

which contains $x = \sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} \dfrac{b_n}{2^{2n+1}} + \sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} \dfrac{a_{2n}}{2^{2n}}$ for any binary sequence $a_{2n}$ defined as above, so it is uncountable

Comment: ...and for the numbers like 1 the construction is much easier than this to-remember one. +1.

Answer (score 0):

I assume it means "*uncountably*" often, i.e., assumes each value uncountably-many times.
Maybe you can consider a variant of tangent.